# Adding a class to the closest href

Tags: jquery, html-lists, addclass

I'm using jQuery to addClass to a closest href with the class **mitem** .

but it does not work ...

The problem is that, with the code like this, it adds the **act** class to all the **a** elements in the menu and not only the closest **a** element .

maybe I should use something else ? or maybe something is wrong in the way I wrote the code ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#nav").hover(function(){ 
    //$('ul li.current').addClass('act');
    $(this).closest("a.mitem").addClass("act");
  }, 
  function () {
     $(".mitem").removeClass('act');
  }
  );    

});
</script>

        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#" class="mitem mhome" title="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="mitem mshop" title="">shop</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li class="mheader"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hard Drives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Speakers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Random Equipment</a></li>
                </ul>            
            </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: Why not use `$("#nav li a").hover` and add the class to `this`?

Comment: Do you want this to add the attribute to each `a` element as the user hovers over it?

Answer (score 1):

you're attaching the hover event to the entire ul element #nav, so the closest anchor will always be the first one, even if you use an actual jQuery method to traverse such as `find()` or `children()`

assuming you want the anchor tag to have the class added when the parent element is hovered over, you could do this:

```
$('#nav>li').on('hover', function() {
    $('.mitem').removeClass('act');
    $(this).find('a.mitem').addClass('act');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the first descendant under `this` that matches your selector:

```
$(this).find('a.mitem').first()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HXp9b/1/)

Answer (score 0):

someone else posted the answer and then deleted it for some reason, but it's the only one working for me so here it is :

```
$("#nav li").has("ul").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("current").children("ul").fadeIn();
    $(this).children("a.mitem:first").addClass("act");

}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current").children("ul").hide();
    $(this).children("a.mitem:first").removeClass("act");

});
```